# Get the 10 from 1-10 out from the text using regular expression

Tags: php, regex

Let's say i have an example text like this "1-10 this is a text 1000 records."

how can I get the number 10 from it using regular expression
im using PHP. is

```
preg_match('/[^-0-9]/', '', $text)
```

good ?

Comment: If you want to *get* the number, *replacing* it probably isn't what you want.

Comment: I've edited the question, should've been preg_match

Comment: Use `/\d+-\K\d+/`

Comment: thanks! but what does \K do?

Comment: `\K` is a reset match operator so whatever got captured by `\d+-` in the beginning will be reset and will not be captured in the matched text, hence `\d+` that follows `\K` will capture value `10` for you

Comment: awesome. thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `preg_replace` `preg_match` function takes first argument as the regex that needs to be matched, second argument as the string in which the regex is applied for matching and third argument is the variable where the matches will be stored. For capturing `10` out of `1-10 this is a text 1000 records.`, you can exploit the occurrence of `-` just before the digit you intend to capture and can write a regex like this,

```
-(\d+)
```

Which basically will look for a hyphen `-` and will capture whatever number having 1 or more digits in group1. In php you can access it like this,

```
$s = "1-10 this is a text 1000 records.";
preg_match('/-(\d+)/', $s, $m);
print($m[1]); // m[0] will contain full match and m[1] will contain text matched by group1
```

Which prints,

```
10
```

Comment: I'd accept that answer but I just wanna know which is more "proficient" between anubhava's answer

Comment: @dashred: You can use any in this case. `\K` is useful primarily in a condition, when you want to search some text that is enclosed by certain text and you can't do variable length look behind, then `\K` comes really handy.

Comment: Glad to help :)